# What is preventing compile time evaluation of this constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++17, stm32, constexpr, constexpr-function

I'm working on a class for representing a set of hardware pins of a microcontroller (STM32). The selected pins may be discontinuous on the port, but they are assumed to be ordered. For example, if this `PortSegment` object is created to represent PA2, PA3 & PA6 pins, I want to be able to make an assignment like `segment = 0b101u` , which sets PA2 & PA6 and resets PA3.

Currently I haven't implemented *ctor* for discontinuous pins yet. The current one allows representing only continuous pins like PA2, P3 & PA4. However, the logic for mapping *compressed* bits (like `0b101u` in the above example) to actual hardware bits is implemented for the discontinuous case.

I thought an assignment like `segment = 0b101u` could be calculated mostly on compile time, and only the loading the actual hardware register (`BSRR` for STM32, which handles atomic set & reset of hardware pins) takes place during run time, using a pre-calculated value. Unfortunately this isn't what happens and the value to be loaded into `BSRR` is also calculated in run time.

Here is the somewhat simplified and half-baked version of the code I'm testing. Port selection (GPIOA, GPIOB etd.) code is omitted.

```
#include <cstdint>

volatile uint32_t BSRR {0}; // Assume it's a HW register for atomic pin access.

class PortSegment {
public:

    constexpr PortSegment(uint8_t start, uint8_t end)
    : selection{calculateSelection(start, end)} {}

    uint16_t operator=(uint16_t setVal) const;
//  operator uint16_t() const; // to be implemented later

private:

    static constexpr uint16_t calculateSelection(uint8_t start, uint8_t end);
    static constexpr uint16_t mapBits(uint16_t val, uint16_t selection);

    uint16_t selection; // Table of used bits in the port

};

// Used in ctor
constexpr uint16_t PortSegment::calculateSelection(uint8_t start, uint8_t end)
{
    uint16_t result {0};
    for (unsigned i = start; i <= end; ++i) result |= (1u << i);
    return result;
}

// static function
constexpr uint16_t PortSegment::mapBits(uint16_t val, uint16_t selection)
{
    uint16_t result {0};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        if (selection & 1u)  {
            if (val & (1u << i)) {
                result |= (1u << i);
            }
        }
        else {
            val <<= 1;
        }
        selection >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

inline uint16_t PortSegment::operator=(uint16_t setVal) const
{
    uint32_t mapped {mapBits(setVal, selection)};
    BSRR = ((~mapped << 16) | mapped)
            & ((static_cast<uint32_t>(selection) << 16) | selection);
    return setVal;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr PortSegment segment {2,5}; // Use port pins 2,3,4,5
    segment = 0b1010u;
}
```

The `selection` member variable represents the pins used in the port. For example, `0b111100` means use PA2, PA3, PA4, PA5. The problem is that, the `mapBits()` function is not evaluated during compile time. I also tried to make it non-static member function, but nothing changed. According to my logic, when the `segment` object of `PortSegment` class created, everything is already known during compile time, and the value to be loaded into `BSRR` could also be known. But it seems I'm missing something.

Another strange thing I discovered that, if I change `selection >>= 1;` in the `mapBits()` function to `selection <<= 1;` (which makes no sense for the algorithm), `mapBits()` can be calculated compile time.

Here is the [code in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9qqMfY6cK).

Comment: Your operator of assignation is .. `const`?

Comment: `mapBits` is not used in constexpr context, so is no required to be done at compile time, up to optimizer.

Comment: @Jarod42 Assignment operator doesn't actually change the state of the object. It's intended for loading the hardware `BSRR` register only, which isn't part of the class.

Comment: off topic: `operator=` which doesn't assign anything and doesn't return `*this` (`PortSegment &`)can screw future maintainer. Now this assign operator is a lie, this should be some function with name which explains what it does.

Comment: `gcc` compiles your code to a single `movl` instruction, going as far back as version 6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set optimisation to level 1 in Godbolt! Try `-O3` instead of `-O1`.

Comment: You're right! I'm generally not used to work with high optimization levels on embedded systems, so I overlooked it. Actually, I had tried -O2 but completely forgot -O3. Thanks!